# Has the voting quota changed recently, or am I simply voting more?

Tags: support

For the last two or three days in a row, I've gotten a message that I've reached my daily voting limit.

I don't remember ever seeing this message before (well, maybe once, a while ago?), so I'm wondering whether the threshold has changed recently, either globally or for me specifically, or whether I'm simply voting more and haven't noticed.

If I'm remembering what the modal popup said, my daily quota is 40 votes. Is that normal? Is anyone aware of any recent changes in his area? Is the threshold the same for all users, or does it tune itself to each user's voting pattern (e.g. to prevent fraud or voting binges)?

Please note I'm asking about regular voting on questions and answers here, not close- or delete-voting.

(Sorry if this is an obvious question, I have a hard time searching Meta.SE on occasion.)

Comment: It is called *the serial voter syndrome* :), anyway no change in daily voting limit  I am aware of.

Comment: It's hit me a bit lately too. I think the basic questions that are mistakenly posted here rather than on ELL sometimes seem to come in waves, and there can be a *lot* of them. Especially since from my point of view if I'm going through the review queue and I've just closevoted three questions for that reason, I'm inclined to be a bit harsh if the fourth question leans a bit in that direction. [Which just happened today!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251455/) (Sorry Yoichi! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's been 40 for years. And you can only vote on 30 answers.